# Android mock TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR with out Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, static, mocking, robolectric

Trying to remove Robolectric from test cases.

Stuck with references to TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR which is null without Robolectric.

Any ideas on how to mock a static final field in android tests?
Can't use any more libraries, have to remove robo.